# create links inside <router-link> on multiple html elements

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and to create multiple styled `v-card`, each card should contain link to a target but only by clicking the card's internal title or image. The problem is that I'm looping over my array of object's and wrapping each `v-card` with `<router-link>` so the entire card is clickable. here is the code:

```
<router-link v-for="recipe in recipes" :key="recipe.title" :to="{path: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}">
  <v-card>
      <v-img :src="require('../assets/foodpic.jpg')" aspect-ratio="2.75"></v-img>

      <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{ recipe.title }}</h3>
          </div>
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange" disabled>Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</router-link>
```

i found a way to attach router link to specific element using `tags` but that only allows me to connect single html element and here i want to use the same link on multiple elements.
any idea how can i modify this code so only the `v-img` and `v-card-title` will be linked to the recipe?

Comment: Can't you use `:to` on `v-card`?

Answer (score 0):

hope it works for you

```
 <v-card v-for="recipe in recipes" :key="recipe.title">
      <v-img :src="require('../assets/foodpic.jpg')" aspect-ratio="2.75" 
      :to="{path: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}"></v-img>


      <v-card-title primary-title :to="{path: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}">
          <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{ recipe.title }}</h3>
          </div>
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange" disabled>Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
```

Comment: nope doesn't work. i tried to manipulate it with `<router-link>` and still doesn't work.

Comment: change this :to="{path: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}" to :to="{name: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}"

Answer (score 0):

i ended up setting it like this:

```
<v-card v-for="recipe in recipes" :key="recipe.title">
    <router-link :to="{path: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}">
        <v-img :src="require('../assets/foodpic.jpg')" aspect-ratio="2.75"></v-img>
    </router-link>
    <v-card-title primary-title>
        <div>
            <router-link :to="{path: `recipe/${recipe.title}`}">
                {{ recipe.title }}
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn flat color="orange" disabled>Share</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```